# Git - Custom command "cd"

Tags: git

Is it possible in the git custom command to change the *console bash directory*?

My example code:

```
#!/bin/bash
# This is a test
cd /c/testfolder
ls
```

the code is working, but the `cd` only works on this block doesn't do any alteration on the bash.
[image]

So what I need it is the console `/` change to `/c/testfolder`

Comment: https://alanbarber.com/post/how-to-customize-the-git-for-windows-bash-shell-prompt/ may help. `MINGW64` is part of `PS1`.

Comment: @ElpieKay Thanks, but I want a need is to make the cd works outside of the script block, I edit the question removing the MINGW64 mention.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not possible for a command or shell script to cause the shell / console's current directory to change.

<sup>(Unless you are executing the script in the shell itself using `source` / `.`.  You can't do that with a `git` custom command because they are executed by a child process of `git` not by the console's shell.)</sup>

See [Bash script to change parent shell directory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13753157/bash-script-to-change-parent-shell-directory) for a more detailed explanation of the *base* problem.